# Plot Lorenz system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I solved the Lorenz system by using [Euler](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=euler%20forward%20method) forward method (without using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)). But I am not getting the attractor. The *Mathematica* code is as follows

```
Clear[x, y, z]
x[0] = 0; y[0] = 1; z[0] = 0;
Do[x[n + 1] = x[n] + .01 ( -3 ( x[n] - y[n])), {n, 0, 100}]
Do[y[n + 1] = y[n] + .01 (-x[n] z[n] + 28 x[n] - y[n]), {n, 0, 100}]
Do[z[n + 1] = z[n] + .01 (x[n] y[n] - z[n]), {n, 0, 100}]
Plot[{z[n], y[n], z[n]}, {n, 0, 100}]
```

Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**.Choose a meaningful name.  **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your `Plot` command does not contain `x[n]` but instead has `z[n]` twice.

Answer (score 12):

Another version:

```
euler[{x_, y_, z_}] := 
 {x + .01 (-3 (x - y)),y + .01 (-x z + 28 x - y),z + .01 (x y - z)}

steps = 1000;
init = {0, 1, 0};

sol = NestList[euler, init, steps];

(* ListLinePlot[Transpose@sol] *)
p = Interpolation /@ Transpose@sol;
Plot[Evaluate@Through@p@x, {x, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

**Edit**
(@belisarius comment)

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  Through@p@x, {x, 1, 1000}, 
  PlotPoints -> 1000,ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &)]
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

The OP works with Mathematica $5.0$. In this version the procedures `ListLinePlot` and `ListPlot[..., Joined->true]`are not introduced. With this edit it should work.

Comment: For your second plot probably `p = Interpolation /@ Transpose@sol; ParametricPlot3D[
 Through@p@x, {x, 1, 1000}]` is cleaner

Comment: @belisarius Thank you, I edit this.

Comment: Thank You. I have Mathematica 5. Is this run the above code. I am copy the code and run... they are shown some error...

Comment: @G Velmurugan It works with Mathematica 10.2  perfectly. I don't have Mathematica 5 and cannot help further.

Comment: @G Velmurugan  I have made an edit, so it should work in Mathematica 5.0. Unfortunately I can not test it.

Comment: Thank You Willinski. I have download Mathematica 9 and install it. Now the code is works. Further, any query I will contact.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Clear[x, y, z]

x[n_] := x[n] = x[n - 1] + .01 (-3 (x[n - 1] - y[n - 1]))
y[n_] := y[n] = y[n - 1] + .01 (-x[n - 1] z[n - 1] + 28 x[n - 1] - y[n - 1])
z[n_] := z[n] = z[n - 1] + .01 (x[n - 1] y[n - 1] - z[n - 1])

x[0] = 0; 
y[0] = 1; 
z[0] = 0;

limitN = 1000;
resAll = Table[{x[n], y[n], z[n]}, {n, 0, limitN}];

ListLinePlot[{resAll[[;; , 1]], resAll[[;; , 2]], resAll[[;; , 3]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x[n]", "y[n]", "z[n]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "n=" <> ToString[limitN]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. I have Mathematica 5. Is this run the above code. I am copy the code and run... they are shown some error...

Comment: @GVelmurugan Yes, it's the code for the shown plot. I don't get an error with version 10. What error do you get?

Comment: Thank You Phab. I have download Mathematica 9 and install it. Now the code is works. Further, any query I will contact.